# Не запускается эмулятор Android Studio на AMD

Tags: android-studio, amd, android-emulator

Всем добрый день. Пересел с Intel на новый компьютер с процессором AMD Ryzen 5 5600x(Windows10). В BIOS включил виртуализацию(SVM mode). Отключил компоненты windows hyper-v(вроде все)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Android Studio установил hypervisor driver fo AMD (1.6.0)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но эмулятор всё равно не запускается, просто убивается процесс. В логах ничего не отображается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто сталкивался с подобным, помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63317727/android-emulator-the-emulator-process-for-avd-was-killed-windows-intel) решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: @SurfaceStack, не нашёл там ничего, что помогало бы